# Fragment is destroyed when nav back from Fiori Launchpad?

Tags: sapui5

I use 2 XML fragment, one for display data, the other for edit.

I switch the fragment using this method:

```
onAfterRendering : function () {
    this._toggleForm("Display");
},

_toggleForm : function(sFragmentName) {
    var oPage = this._detailPage;

    //my detail page has an object header, a fragment form and a form in detail view.
    if(oPage.getContent().length > 2) {
        oPage.removeContent(1);
    }
    oPage.insertContent(this._getFormFragment(sFragmentName), 1);
},

_formFragments: {},

_getFormFragment: function (sFragmentName) {
    var oFormFragment = this._formFragments[sFragmentName],
    oView = this.getView();

    if (oFormFragment) {
        return oFormFragment;
    }

    oFormFragment = sap.ui.xmlfragment(oView.getId(), "namespace.fragment." + sFragmentName, this);
    oView.addDependent(oFormFragment);

    return this._formFragments[sFragmentName] = oFormFragment;
}
```

Everything works fine... BUT, if I call the app from the Fiori launchpad, the first call is ok, but the second time give me this error in `insertContent` :

> The object with ID XXX-detail--general was destroyed and cannot be used anymore.

Comment: Why don't you use editable state for the form elements? It's easier than destroying and switching fragments.. Don't you think so?

Comment: @AndriiNaumovych, thanks for you suggestion, I updated my reason in my answer, if there is any mistake, you're more than welcome to correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display/Change fragment is destroyed after exit, but this._fromFragment still stored a reference, and returned this reference `oFormFragment` when `_getFormFragment` is called when I entered the second time, which caused this error.

Fixed by add:

```
        onExit : function () {
            for(var sPropertyName in this._formFragments) {
                if(!this._formFragments.hasOwnProperty(sPropertyName)) {
                    return;
                }

                this._formFragments[sPropertyName].destroy();
                this._formFragments[sPropertyName] = null;
            }
        }
```

---

Answer @AndriiNaumovych 's question:

It seems that only `sap.ui.comp.smartform.SmartForm` has a [EditTogglable](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.comp.smartform.SmartForm.html#setEditTogglable) property, and it need a `sap:updatable="true"` in metadata.xml (I saw that in [Explore](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smartform/code/mockserver%252Fmetadata.xml), not specified in doc.)

I use `sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm`, `editable` seems not working in JSON model without metadata. So I use [this example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.layout.sample.SimpleForm354/preview) with fragment.